# Кнопка, чувствительная к движению мыши

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Нужно реализовать кнопку, чувствительную к движению мыши, которая при наведении на нее должна двигаться в любую из сторон от курсора. Реализовать смог только так:

```
 Random rnd = new Random();
    private void button1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Location = new Point(rnd.Next(this.Width - button1.Width), rnd.Next(this.Height - button1.Height));
    }
```

Но по итогу кнопка не двигается, а перемещается мгновенно на другую точку. Как мне реализовать ее передвижение ?

Comment: Можете ввести зависимость модуля перемещения от расстояния курсора до кнопки, чем ближе курсор - тем дальше "убегает кнопка", так будет немного плавнее. Так же учтите что Location - это положение левого верхнего угла контрола, а не его центра.

Comment: @SmorcIRL Только начал изучение данной темы, подскажите пожалуйста, что такое зависимость модуля перемещения?

Comment: Имел в виду просто насколько далеко двигать кнопку, в зависимости от расстояния курсора до границ кнопки

Comment: @SmorcIRL А возможно ли сделать так, чтобы при наведении на кнопку она перемещалась не сразу, а например через 2-3 секунды? Как такое реализовать?

Comment: @SmorcIRL Что можно использовать вместо Location, чтобы отметить положение центра контрола?

Comment: С таймаутом - можно, удобнее всего через асинхронные обработчики событий и Tasks. Но ивент движения мыши вызывается довольно часто и вам нужно будет решать вопрос что делать с "наложением" таких отсроченных перемещений, 2-3 секунды это всё-же довольно долго.

Вместо Location можете выбирать либо центр кнопки либо, что лучше - границы. Например если мышь двигается справа и сверху, смотрите расстояние по x - до верхей границы, по y - до правой границы. Границы и центр можно определить геометрически через Location, Width и Height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь нужно немного математики и совсем капелька асинхронного программирования.

К примеру, нужна (самодельная) анимация передвижения с частотой отрисовки 30 кадров в секунду, тогда задержка между кадрами будет `1 / 30 = 33мс`. Следовательно нужен цикл, тело которого будет выполняться примерно раз в 33 миллисекунды.

Теперь нужно определиться с шагом, здесь нужно выяснить, а сколько времени кнопка будет "бежать" из одной точки в другую. Давайте допустим, что это 1 секунда, тогда шаг - это будет расстояние поделенное на количество "кадров" в 1 секунде, то есть 30. Тогда шаг - это будет 1/30 расстояния от старого положения кнопки до нового.

Ну и реализовать теперь это интуитивно просто.

```cs
private bool isRunning; // защита от повторного запуска новой анимации до окончания предыдущей
// async метод
private async void button1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (isRunning) return;
    isRunning = true;
    int x = button1.Location.X;
    int y = button1.Location.Y;
    int duration = 1000; // длительность в миллисекундах
    int fps = 30 * duration / 1000; // 30 кадров/сек, но длительность может отличаться от 1000, поэтому пересчёт
    int delay = duration / fps;

    int newX = rnd.Next(this.Width - button1.Width);
    int newY = rnd.Next(this.Height - button1.Height);
    int stepX = (newX - x) / fps;
    int stepY = (newY - y) / fps;
    for (int i = 0; i < fps; i++)
    {
        button1.Location = new Point(x + stepX * i, y + stepY * i);
        await Task.Delay(delay); // асинхронное ожидание
    }
    // конечные координаты могут быть не точными из-за округления, поэтому я добавил вот это, чтобы исправить
    button1.Location = new Point(newX, newY); 
    isRunning = false;
}
```

Comment: Именно то что нужно! Подскажите пожалуйста, где можно узнать более об "Асинхронном программировании"?

Comment: @xxxzeddd [Асинхронное программирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async).

Comment: Возникла проблема при добавлении MessageBox. Вот код
`private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(
                "Вы выиграли",
                "Сообщение",
        MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
        MessageBoxIcon.Information,
        MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1,
        MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly);
        }`
Почему после нажатия на кнопку, MessageBox показывается не сразу, а кнопка начинает летать  за видимые пределы окна